# Why is my getServerSideProps coming back as undefined within my nextjs app (I am using a class component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Okay, so here is my problem.  I am getting props via getserversideprops, and I have tried multiple fixes but I can not get it to display.  Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import rpstyle from '/styles/home/recentPosts.module.css'

export default class RecentPosts extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = { posts: this.props.posts }
    }

    static async getServerSideProps() {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/search/recentposts')
        const json = await res.json()
        return { posts : json }
    }



    viewAllButton(){
        if(this.props.viewAll != false){
            return (
                <div className={rpstyle.viewAll}>
                    <a href='#'>View All Posts</a>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={rpstyle.container}>
                <hr />
                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
                {console.log(this.props.posts)}
                {this.viewAllButton()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

For some reason I can not find a good guide for class-based components and this method.  If someone has any ideas on making this not display `undefined` please let me know!

Comment: getServerSideProps needs to be _exported_ from the nextjs page's file rather than a property of a class component

Comment: I did that within the index.js page file, and it is still showing undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I took a little bit from your answers as well some more research and found this to work great:

```
import Recentstuff from '../components/home/recentposts/RecentPosts'

export default function Home({data}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Recentstuff posts={data} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/search/recentposts')
  const data = await res.json()
  return { props : {data} }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who had the same issue.  You have to call it within the page file, the pass it as a prop.  MAKE SURE you properly destructure it, because I had a good little time tracking down why my api calls were showing on my api but not within my client.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use the same api  for classes as well, if you are using a recent version of next you need to change the return object of getServerSideProps, it needs to have a props key

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class RecentPosts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { posts: props.data }
    }

    viewAllButton(){
        if(this.props.viewAll != false){
            return (
                <div className={rpstyle.viewAll}>
                    <a href='#'>View All Posts</a>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <hr />
                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
                {console.log(this.state)}
                {/* {this.viewAllButton()} */}
            </>
        )
    }
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    const json = await res.json()
    return { props : json }
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately I am still getting ```undefined``` from this as well, it shows up as posts: undefined