# getServerSideProps on a page returns undefined props if router.replace called in _app.tsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have `getServerSideProps` in a page, eg `index.tsx`. (Not in a component like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458506/why-getserversideprops-returns-undefined) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962619/why-is-my-getserversideprops-coming-back-as-undefined-within-my-nextjs-app-i-am))

...and it is `export`ed (This is not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978939/getserversideprops-returns-undefined) problem)

Here's the basic code structure

```
index.tsx:

import processRequest from '../lib/processRequest';

const Index = ({ otherStuffPassedFrom_appjs, data }) => {
  console.log(data) // undefined
  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const data = await processRequest(...stuff extracted from the context);
  console.log(data); // data exists here
  return { props : {data} };
}
```

The weirdest thing is that if I put a breakpoint on the `return { props : {data} };` line, and then run manually from there, the `data` shows up in the client's `console.log()`.

`processRequest` is a complex function with many `async` `await` calls to APIs and a firestore DB and I'm not able to share the details.  `processRequest` must be run on multiple pages, which is why I put in a `lib` file.

I have checked that `await`s are applied to all `async` function calls in `processRequest` and descendant function calls.

Grateful for any clues on how to debug or what more to try out.

UPDATE:

I found the conflicting code, I think. I also had

```
_app.tsx:

import { useRouter } from "../node_modules/next/router";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const router = useRouter();
  if (route contained particular query string) {
    router.replace(router.basePath); // remove the query string
  }
  ...
  return (
    <Component {...{ ...pageProps }} />
  );
}
```

`processRequest` does stuff particularly when this query string is present, so the effect of the code above is to process the query string, and then remove it.

Both the client and server `console.log`s were happening twice, the first on the server had `data`, but the second was `undefined`.

When I removed the `router.replace` the client was reporting the console.log on the first call (`undefined` on the second, which was after the query string was removed, as expected).

Incidentally, it calls the client `console.log` 6 times if I put the `router.replace` in index.js instead: 2 times with `data` and 4 `undefined`.

So is this a bug with `_app` and `router.replace`?

Comment: if you `console.log(data)` after `const data = await processRequest()` is the data object is defined ?

Comment: good question @AhmedSbai, yes it does. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: try to return a simple object as props like `{a: 'aa', b: 'bb'}` and see if it does not work try to change `data` to `myData` for example maybe the compont is reciving another data I don't know but your code is simple and should work

Comment: I updated the question after further findings prompted by your question, @AhmedSbai